# Not able to download Article Inline attachment using Oath -2 Authentication

Tags: knowledge, articles, inline

I am trying to download inline attachments using OAuth-2.0 authentication API in salesforce. But when I try to download the image I am getting a script downloaded.
which looks like below -

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<script>
function redirectOnLoad() {
if (this.SfdcApp && this.SfdcApp.projectOneNavigator) { SfdcApp.projectOneNavigator.handleRedirect('
```

The inline attachment url looks like this -

> https://dev-portal-data.file.force.com/servlet/rtaImage?eid=ka11Q0XXXXXXXlah&feoid=00N3600000XXXXX&refid=0EM1Q00000XXXX

What I am doing is just session.get(url, stream ="true") and it is not downloading the image for me.
I am passing Authorization as Bearer Token and "Content-Type": "application/json".